# Regex : how to replace only specific strings in file

Tags: regex, linux, shell, unix

With a shell script, I'm trying to replace a specific part of a string.

Here is an extract of the file and its content:

```
\"filename\":\"screenreader\"}', '{\"registration_email\":\"toto@toto.com\",\"read_page\":\"1\"
\"unique_pagination\":\"1\",\"registration_email\":\"toto@toto.com\",\"searchbox_enable\":\"0\",\
\"filename\":\"jspeed\"}', '{\"registration_email\":\"toto@toto.com\",\"combine_files_enable\":\"1\"
```

I would like to replace all the **toto@toto.com** strings by another string.
But the string **toto@toto.com** won't be systematically the same...can be **tata@tata.com** or whatever.

Here is my SED command inside shell script :

```
sed -i -e 's/\\"registration_email\\":\\".*\\"/\\"registration_email\\":\\"TATATATATA\\"/g' file.txt
```

This command works, the string is correctly replaced, but the end of each line is removed and the result is the following :

```
\"filename\":\"screenreader\"}', '{\"registration_email\":\"TATATATATA\"
\"unique_pagination\":\"1\",\"registration_email\":\"TATATATATA\",\
\"filename\":\"jspeed\"}', '{\"registration_email\":\"TATATATATA\"
```

Expected result should be the following :

```
\"filename\":\"screenreader\"}', '{\"registration_email\":\"TATATATATA\",\"read_page\":\"1\"
\"unique_pagination\":\"1\",\"registration_email\":\"TATATATATA\",\"searchbox_enable\":\"0\",\
\"filename\":\"jspeed\"}', '{\"registration_email\":\"TATATATATA\",\"combine_files_enable\":\"1\"
```

So how can I replace the string, without removing the end of each lines?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Enable regular expression with -r and split lines into three sections. Substitute the line for the first and second sections, followed by the replacement email and the 4th section

```
sed -rn 's/(^.*)(registration_email\\":\\")(.*@.*)(\\",\\".*$)/\1\2TATATATATA\4/p' file
```

To commit to file

```
sed -ri 's/(^.*)(registration_email\\":\\")(.*@.*)(\\",\\".*$)/\1\2TATATATATA\4/' file
```

Comment: ok but the string is not necessary an email. could be a number, a texte, etc.. in your example, works only for a mail?

Comment: any idea about that ?